# Atomic Batch Commit of Write Streams Across Multiple BigQuery Tables using Java Client Library

Tags: google-bigquery, google-bigquery-java

I am working on a project where I need to stream data into multiple BigQuery tables using the Java client library.
I would like to create write streams for each table and then batch commit these write streams atomically.

I have been trying to do this :

```
 var request = BatchCommitWriteStreamsRequest.newBuilder()
              .addWriteStreams("stream-table-1")
              .addWriteStreams("stream-table-2")
                  .build();
 
client.batchCommitWriteStreams(request);
```

However I found that all stream should belong to the same Table.

is there any solution to commit different streams of different tables atomatically ?

Comment: Hi @maroodb, Does these 2 [link1](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage/rpc/google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1#google.cloud.bigquery.storage.v1.BigQueryWrite.BatchCommitWriteStreams) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api-batch-load) will help you ?